# Bad operand type for binary operator

Tags: java

I am writing a program(this is part of it):

```
for (int a = 0; a<=firstsplit.length-1; a++)
  {
  //skipping over values that say how many pieces are on board
      for (int i = 3; i <= 12; i++)
      {
      //compatible with piece numbers up to 12(max)
        if (Integer.parseInt(firstsplit[0])==i) {
           while (a >= 1 && a <= firstsplit[i]) {
                      continue;
                      }
      }
      }
   }
```

And this error is occurring:

```
Board.java:41: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='
           while (a >= 1 && a <= firstsplit[i]) {
                              ^
first type:  int
second type: String
1 error
```

Any help to solve this would be appreciated. I am not an advanced programmer, as you can probably tell.

Comment: How would you compare an `int` and a `String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing correctly here:

```
Integer.parseInt(firstsplit[0])==i
```

But not here:

```
a <= firstsplit[i]
```

Do you see what you need to do?

Comment: Thank you. I should pay more attention next time.